# (CMAKE) Compile 32 bit on 64 bit system (error adding symbols: File in wrong format)

Tags: linux, boost, cmake

I have a cpp project which uses a 32 bit library. When i build and run the app i get this error:

> dlopen:./lib.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Thats why i'm trying to build this project 32 bit.

Here is my cmakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(app)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(app main.cpp a.c a.h)
set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem thread REQUIRED)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(app ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -pthread")
endif()

target_link_libraries(app ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

I get this error:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so: error adding symbols:
>   File in wrong format

When i delete Boost block and compile, no problem. When i delete .so file and build on 64bit, no problem. But i have to use this library and use libboost too.

What's the correct cmakeList in this situation?